# Windows 10 Graphics Issue

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-studio-2019

I recently purchased a used Dell Inspiron 7591 2in1 its an i7 model with 16Gb Ram and an NVidia MX250 GPU

I installed Windows 10 Enterprise along with all the drivers required using Dell's Support Assistant. I have been facing weird glitches in graphics, not wavy or cloured lines or anything like that but just missing texts or graphics, or overlapping texts, etc.

example:
Start Menu

[image: Start Menu]
Settings

[image: Settings]
Visual Studio Start Screen
[image: Visual Studio]
Visual Studio Application Window
[image: VS Window]

Comment: Have you contacted your IT Administrator.  I suspect some of the glitches are due to a group policy since it appears you are connected to an AD domain.  Windows is also not activated, which could have something to do with the (Windows) behavior, you are experiencing.  Have you tried to activate your installation?

Comment: Hi, I am the Admin :), we have not activated any machines on our network, didn't face the problem seen here. Also, we have the same GPO applied on multiple computers (part of the same OU) don't see the same problem. either.